# VBA - If PivotItem is Visible

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, pivotitem

I have some vba code which I would like to run if a PivotItem is visible and another piece of code to run if it isn't visible.
When I run this sub and the item is switched on it doesn't recognise that it is visible.

```
Sub test()

If Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TestField").PivotItems("TestItem").Value = xlOn Then
MsgBox "is on"
Else: MsgBox "is off"
End If

End Sub
```

Cheers

Comment: Did you try to `Refresh` your table?

Comment: Yes and running this sub does still not work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the visible property not the value property of the pivotitem.

Try this:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TestField").PivotItems("TestItem").Visible = True Then
```

Comment: Using this still doesn't work. In other code if i was to set the item to be visible or not that code would be fine. But for some reason detecting whether it is or not is a different story.

Comment: I made a test pivot table and tested this exactly and it works as expected. Perhaps there is an error in the name of the pivottable, pivotfields or pivotitem. You could try recording a macro using the pivot table, pivot field and pivot item in question and see what it says the names of those items are.